# Prove $(\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x})^3+12\ge 13(x^3+y^3+z^3)$ for positives $xyz = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, substitution, symmetric-polynomials, uvw

> let $x,y,z>0$, and such
> $xyz=1$,show that
> $$\left(\dfrac{x^2}{y}+\dfrac{y^2}{z}+\dfrac{z^2}{x}\right)^3+12\ge 13(x^3+y^3+z^3)\tag{1}$$

I have konwn use C-S we have
$$\left(\dfrac{x^2}{y}+\dfrac{y^2}{z}+\dfrac{z^2}{x}\right)\ge\dfrac{(x+y+z)^2}{x+y+z}=x+y+z$$
this relsut can't sove this inequality $(1)$,so How to prove it?and if use $pqr$ methods,$x+y+z=p,xy+yz+xz=q,xyz=r=1$,but
$$\sum \dfrac{x^2}{y}=\dfrac{\sum x^3z}{xyz}=\sum x^3z$$

Comment: Do you know anything about the theory of symmetric polynomials? You should be able to write $\sum x^3z$ in terms of $p, q,$ and $r$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki It isn’t symmetric, its cyclic.  So “pqr” etc won’t work till this is reduced to some symmetric bound.

Comment: @Macavity,I can write,But it's very ugly

Comment: Yes, of course. We'll get  24-degree inequality.

Answer (score 2):

The hint.

By the $uvw$'s technique prove that:
$$\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}\geq\frac{5(x^2+y^2+z^2)-2(xy+xz+yz)}{x+y+z}.$$
After this by $uvw$ prove that:
$$\frac{5(x^2+y^2+z^2)-2(xy+xz+yz)}{x+y+z}\geq\sqrt[3]{13(x^3+y^3+z^3)-12xyz}.$$
A proof of the second inequality.

Let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$, $xyz=w^3$ and $u^2=tv^2$.

Thus, $t\geq1$ and we need to prove that
$$\frac{5(9u^2-6v^2)-6v^2}{3u}\geq\sqrt[3]{13(27u^3-27uv^2+3w^3)-12w^3}$$ or
$$(5u^2-4)^3\geq u^3(13u^3-13uv^2+w^3).$$
Now, since $uw^3\leq v^4,$ it's enough to prove that
$$(5t-4)^3\geq t(13t^2-13t+1)$$ or
$$(t-1)(112t^2-175t+64)\geq0$$ or
$$t-1+7(t-1)^2(16t-9)\geq0,$$ which is obvious for $t\geq1$.

Comment: Thanks,the last  inequality how to prove it?

Comment: it is said the first can use two Cauchy-schwarz inequality to solve it,and the second inequality  can use AM-GM inequality to solve it,can you konwn it?Thanks

Comment: $\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}\geq\frac{5(x^2+y^2+z^2)-2(xy+xz+yz)}{x+y+z}$ is very nice.

Comment: @River Li Yes, because it's enough.  $\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}\geq\frac{37(x^2+y^2+z^2)-19(xy+xz+yz)}{6(x+y+z)}$ is stronger.

Comment: Thank you for your interest!

Answer (score 0):

**Supplement to Michael Rozenberg's nice answer**:

We give an alternative proof of the following result.

**Fact 1**: Let $x, y, z > 0$. Then
$$\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}\geq\frac{5(x^2+y^2+z^2)-2(xy+xz+yz)}{x+y+z}.$$

We use the SOS-Schur method.
Please see e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4511251/prove-fracxy2-fracyz2-fraczx2-ge-fracx2y-fracy2z) for some proofs using SOS-Schur method.
In Andreas's nice answer, Remark 2, he gave an algorithm to find $M, N$. That algorithm gives the same $M, N$ as mine.

**Proof of Fact 1**:

WLOG, assume that $z = \max(x, y, z)$.

We have
\begin{align*}
 &\left[\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}-\frac{5(x^2+y^2+z^2)-2(xy+xz+yz)}{x+y+z}\right]xyz(x + y + z)\\[6pt]
 ={}& M(x - y)^2 + N(z - x)(z - y)
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
 M &= x^2(2z - y) + y^2(2z - x),\\
 N &= y(y + z - 2x)^2 + x(x - 2y)^2 + y^3 + xy (z - x).
\end{align*}

Clearly, $M, N \ge 0$.

We are done.