# Prove $\frac{x}{y^2}+\frac{y}{z^2}+\frac{z}{x^2}\ge \frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}$ where $x, y, z > 0$ and $x+y+z=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> Prove $$\frac{x}{y^2}+\frac{y}{z^2}+\frac{z}{x^2}\ge \frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x},$$ where $x,y,z>0$ and $x+y+z=3$.

Maybe we can show $$\frac{x}{y^2}+\frac{y}{z^2}+\frac{z}{x^2}\ge x^3+y^3+z^3,\tag1$$

then $$\frac{x}{y^2}+\frac{y}{z^2}+\frac{z}{x^2}\ge \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{y^2}+x^3+\frac{y}{z^2}+y^3+\frac{z}{x^2}+z^3\right)\ge \frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}.$$

But it's also difficlut to show $(1)$.

Comment: Did u try homogenising ?

Comment: Hint : homogenise and expand , u should be able to solve it with muirhead's

Comment: @AdamBoussif Homogenize how? Set $z=3-x-y$?

Comment: you need to have terms of same degree on each side

Comment: Inelegantly, you can show (1) by Buffalo Way or uvw...

Comment: Interestingly, the order of the cyclicity matters. We have that $\frac{x}{y^2}+\frac{y}{z^2}+\frac{z}{x^2}\ge \frac{x^2}{\color{red}{z}}+\frac{y^2}{\color{red}{x}}+\frac{z^2}{\color{red}{y}}$ does NOT hold, a counterexample is $(x = 3/7 ; y = 12/7 ; z = 6/7)$ which gives $343/48 \color{red}{< } 360/48$.

Answer (score 3):

Homogenizing, we need to show that
$$
f = (x+y+z)^2 (\frac{x}{y^2}+\frac{y}{z^2}+\frac{z}{x^2}) - 9 (\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}) \ge 0
$$
Rewrite $f$ as (see below for some underlying inspiration ...)
$$
f =  (x - y)^2 \frac{5 x^3 + x^2 y + x y^2 + 5 y^3 + (2 z - x - y) (3 x^2 + 8 x y + 3 y^2)}{2 x^2 y^2} + \frac{(z-x)(z-y)}{x^2y^2z^2} \times\\ 
\times  (x^3y^2 + 2x^2y^3 + xy^4 + zy(x^3 + 5x^2y - 4xy^2 + y^3  )+ z^2(x^3 - 6xy^2 + 3y^3)  + y^2z^3) \tag{1}
$$

Let w.l.o.g. by cyclicity, $z \ge x$ and $z \ge y$ and by homogeneity , $z=1$, then we need to show  only for the last bracket that for  $0 \le x,y \le 1$,
$$
g = x^3y^2 + 2x^2y^3 + xy^4 + y(x^3 + 5x^2y - 4xy^2 + y^3  )+ (x^3 - 6xy^2 + 3y^3)  + y^2 > 0
$$
or, expanding in powers of $x$,
$$
g =  x^3 (1 + y + y^2) + y^2 \Big[x^2  (5 + 2 y) + x  (-6 - 4 y + y^2) +  (1 + 3 y + y^2)\Big] > 0 \tag{2}
$$

This is a cubic function in $x$ with one negative coefficient in the linear term, all other coefficients are positive. Since $g(x=0) > 0$, the last two terms guarantee positivity for  $0 < x < 1/6$.

Let us consider $x \ge 1/6$, then $x^3 > x^2/6$ and it suffices to show

$$
h =  x^2 (1 + y + y^2) + 6 y^2 \Big[x^2  (5 + 2 y) + x  (-6 - 4 y + y^2) +  (1 + 3 y + y^2)\Big] > 0
$$

Being a quadratic function in $x$, we have $h(x) = a x^2 + bx + c$ and we can inspect the polynomial discriminant $\Delta = b^2- 4 a c $. This is
$$
\Delta = - 12 y^2 (- 3y^6 + 48 y^5 + 122 y^4 + 68y^3 - 38y^2 + 8 y + 2)\\
\le - 12 y^2 (- 3y^6 + 48 y^6 + 122 y^4 + 68y^3 - 38y^2 + 8 y + 2) \qquad \rm{(*)} \\
= - 12 y^2 (45 y^6 + 122 y^4 + y (68(y - 19/68)^2 + 183/68) + 2) \qquad \rm{(**)} \\
< 0
$$
where (*) is true since $y^5 \ge y^6$ for $0 < y \le1$, and  (**) is true since the terms $68y^3 - 38y^2 + 8 y$ could be formed into a square and a positive part.

Now for negative polynomial discriminant, $h$ has no zeros, and since $h(x=1/6) > 0$, we see that $h\ge 0$ everywhere in $1/6 \le x \le 1$, $0 <  y \le 1$. This proves the claim. $\qquad \Box$

---

Remark 1: Another proof for eq. (2) has been provided in  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4611054/show-positivity-of-a-function-of-two-variables-in-the-unit-square) very elegant post by RiverLi.

Remark 2: Here is some inspiration for arriving at eq. (1). This is rather a working approach report than a formal algorithm of how to arrive at eq. (1).

Suppose that you can write $f(x,y,z) = (x - y)^2 f_1(x,y,z) + (z-x)(z-y) f_2(x,y,z)$. Then $f(x,y,x) = (x-y)^2 f_1(x,y,x)$ and   $f(x,y,y) = (x-y)^2 f_1(x,y,y)$. So, ideally, if $f(x,y,x) - f(x,y,y) = 0$  one  obtains $f_1$ immediately and the other parts follow by polynomial division. However, this approach did not quite work out, but it showed that one could write    $f(x,y,x) - f(x,y,y) = 2(x - y)^3 f_3(x,y)$. This allowed to write  $f(x,y,z) = (x - y)^2 f_1(x,y) + (z-x)(z-y) f_2(x,y,z) + (2z - x - y)^3 f_3(x,y)$. From this follows $(x - y)^2 f_1(x,y) = \lim_{z=x} [f(x,y,z) - (2z - x - y)^3 f_3(x,y)]$ and the remaining part gives $(z-x)(z-y) f_2(x,y,z)$. The result is
\begin{align}
&f =  (x - y)^2 \frac{5 x^3 + x^2 y + x y^2 + 5 y^3}{2 x^2 y^2} + \\ &\quad+ \frac{(z-x)(z-y)}{x^2y^2z^2} (x^3y^2  + 2x^2y^3 + xy^4 + z(x^3y + 5x^2y^2 - 4xy^3 + y^4) + \\
&\quad+z^2 (7x^3  + 22x^2y + 16xy^2 + 9y^3) -  4 z^3(3x^2    + 8xy  + 3y^2) + z^3y^2) + \\
&\quad+(2 z - x - y)^3 \frac{3 x^2 + 8 x y + 3 y^2}{2 x^2 y^2}
\end{align}

This is not immediately helpful, because the term  $-  4 z^3(3x^2    + 8xy  + 3y^2)$ is negative and prevents proving positivity.

Since $(2 z - x - y)^2 = (x - y)^2 + 4 (z-x)(z-y)$ the last term can however be distributed into the two previous terms and we can write this as eq. (1).

Comment: (+1) Perhaps the decomposition $f(a,b,c) = g(a,b,c)(a-b)^2 + h(a,b,c)(c-a)(c-b)$ is the so-called SOS-Schur method.

Comment: @RiverLi yes, this is the underlying concept. However not so straightforward with 3 variables to arrive at the decomposition.

Comment: Did you try SOS-Schur for (1) in OP.

Comment: Remark 2 is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

*Remarks*: Andreas and Michael Rozenberg gave nice proofs using SOS-Schur method, i.e. $f(x, y, z) = M(x-y)^2 + N(z- x)(z-y)$ with $M, N \ge 0$ (assume $z = \max(x, y, z)$).
With the help of computer, we can find many SOS-Schur expressions. Here is one.

WLOG, assume that $z = \max(x, y, z)$.

We have
\begin{align*}
 &\left[\left(\frac{x}{y^2} + \frac{y}{z^2} + \frac{z}{x^2} \right)\frac{(x + y+z)^2}{9} - \left(\frac{x^2}{y} + \frac{y^2}{z} + \frac{z^2}{x}\right)\right]\cdot 9x^2y^2z^2\\[6pt]
 ={}& M(x - y)^2 + N(z - x)(z - y)
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
 M &= (2\,{y}^{2}{z}^{2} + 5xyz^2)\left( z-x \right) +2\,y{z}^{2} \left(z^2 -xy
 \right) +{x}^{3}{z}^{2}+{x}^{2}{y}^{
  3}+2\,{x}^{2}{z}^{3}+xy{z}^{3}+x{z}^{4}, \\
 N &=  \left( 4\,{x}^{2}-3\,xz+{z}^{2} \right) {y}^{3}+ \left( 6\,{x}^{2}-3
 \,xz+{z}^{2} \right) {y}^{2}z.
\end{align*}

Clearly, $M, N \ge 0$.

We are done.

Answer (score 0):

Let :

$$f(x,y,z)=\frac{x}{y^2}+\frac{y}{z^2}+\frac{z}{x^2}- \left(\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}\right)$$

---

---

Then we have :

$$f(x y z/(x y z+1),y z/(y z+1),3-y z/(y z+1)-x y z/(1+x y z))=(2x^{6}y^{8}z^{8}+8x^{6}y^{7}z^{7}+17x^{6}y^{6}z^{6}+16x^{6}y^{5}z^{5}+4x^{6}y^{4}z^{4}+2x^{5}y^{8}z^{8}+10x^{5}y^{7}z^{7}+30x^{5}y^{6}z^{6}+71x^{5}y^{5}z^{5}+70x^{5}y^{4}z^{4}+16x^{5}y^{3}z^{3}+2x^{4}y^{8}z^{8}+10x^{4}y^{7}z^{7}+5x^{4}y^{6}z^{6}+73x^{4}y^{4}z^{4}+101x^{4}y^{3}z^{3}+21x^{4}y^{2}z^{2}+8x^{3}y^{7}z^{7}+30x^{3}y^{6}z^{6}+4x^{3}y^{5}z^{5}-68x^{3}y^{4}z^{4}-21x^{3}y^{3}z^{3}+48x^{3}y^{2}z^{2}+9x^{3}yz+17x^{2}y^{6}z^{6}+81x^{2}y^{5}z^{5}+120x^{2}y^{4}z^{4}+43x^{2}y^{3}z^{3}-18x^{2}y^{2}z^{2}+20xy^{5}z^{5}+108xy^{4}z^{4}+213xy^{3}z^{3}+180xy^{2}z^{2}+54xyz+8y^{4}z^{4}+44y^{3}z^{3}+90y^{2}z^{2}+81yz+27)/(z^{2}y^{2}(yz+1)^{2}x^{2}(xyz+1)^{2}(xy^{2}z^{2}+2xyz+2yz+3)^{2})\geq 0$$

For example :

$$70x^{5}y^{4}z^{4}+120x^{2}y^{4}z^{4}-68x^{3}y^{4}z^{4}> 0$$

---

---

$$f(1+1/(2+x),1+1/(2+xy),1-1/(2+x)-1/(2+xy))=(2y^{6}x^{10}+16y^{6}x^{9}+53y^{6}x^{8}+82y^{6}x^{7}+47y^{6}x^{6}+2y^{5}x^{10}+56y^{5}x^{9}+378y^{5}x^{8}+1143y^{5}x^{7}+1638y^{5}x^{6}+883y^{5}x^{5}+2y^{4}x^{10}+56y^{4}x^{9}+695y^{4}x^{8}+3746y^{4}x^{7}+10074y^{4}x^{6}+13305y^{4}x^{5}+6756y^{4}x^{4}+16y^{3}x^{9}+378y^{3}x^{8}+3750y^{3}x^{7}+17884y^{3}x^{6}+44363y^{3}x^{5}+55092y^{3}x^{4}+26676y^{3}x^{3}+53y^{2}x^{8}+1153y^{2}x^{7}+10213y^{2}x^{6}+44979y^{2}x^{5}+105084y^{2}x^{4}+124308y^{2}x^{3}+57888y^{2}x^{2}+86yx^{7}+1732yx^{6}+14113yx^{5}+58308yx^{4}+129492yx^{3}+146880yx^{2}+66096yx+55x^{6}+1031x^{5}+7848x^{4}+30708x^{3}+65232x^{2}+71280x+31104)/(x^{2}(x+2)^{2}(x+3)^{2}(yx+2)^{2}(yx+3)^{2}(yx+y+1)^{2})>0$$

---

---

We have using the rearrengement inequality for $a,b,c\in(0,3),a+b+c=3$:

$$\frac{a(2.5-a)}{b}+\frac{c(2.5-c)}{a}+\frac{b(2.5-b)}{c}-4.5\geq \frac{a(2.5-a)}{a}+\frac{c(2.5-c)}{c}+\frac{b(2.5-b)}{b}-4.5=0$$

So we have the inequality in my comment  next we use Jensen's inequality to get $f\left(x\right)=x^{-1}-1+\frac{\left(x-1\right)3}{2}$ which is convex for $x\in(0,3)$:

$$\frac{a}{b}f\left(b\right)+\frac{b}{c}f\left(c\right)+\frac{c}{a}f\left(a\right)\ge\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)f\left(\frac{a+b+c}{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}}\right)$$

So the inequality is proven for $\frac{3}{\left( \frac{a}{b}+ \frac{b}{c}+ \frac{c}{a} \right)}\in\left(0,\frac{2}{3}\right)$

We are done !

Comment: For a end remark that $a,b,c>0,a+b+c=3$: $$\frac{a}{b}\left(b^{-1}-1+\frac{\left(b-1\right)3}{2}\right)+\frac{b}{c}\left(c^{-1}-1+\frac{\left(c-1\right)3}{2}\right)+\frac{c}{a}\left(a^{-1}-1+\frac{\left(a-1\right)3}{2}\right)\leq \frac{a}{b^{2}}+\frac{b}{c^{2}}+\frac{c}{a^{2}}-\left(\frac{a^{2}}{b}+\frac{b^{2}}{c}+\frac{c^{2}}{a}\right)$$   because $1+\left(1-x\right)1.5+x>0,x\in[0,3]$ .

Comment: Perhaps we can use Jensen's inequality AFTER replacing the constraint $a+b+c=3$

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=\max\{x,y,z\}.$

Thus, $$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x}{y^2}-\frac{x^2}{y}\right)=$$
$$=\left(\tfrac{x}{y^2}+\tfrac{y}{z^2}+\tfrac{z}{x^2}-\tfrac{1}{x}-\tfrac{1}{y}-\tfrac{1}{z}\right)-\left(\tfrac{x^2}{y}+\tfrac{y^2}{z}+\tfrac{z^2}{x}-x-y-z\right)+\sum_{cyc}\left(\tfrac{1}{x}-1\right)=$$
$$=\left(\tfrac{x}{y^2}+\tfrac{y}{x^2}-\tfrac{1}{x}-\tfrac{1}{y}+\tfrac{y}{z^2}+\tfrac{z}{x^2}-\tfrac{y}{x^2}-\tfrac{1}{z}\right)-\left(\tfrac{x^2}{y}+\tfrac{y^2}{x}-x-y+\tfrac{y^2}{z}+\tfrac{z^2}{x}-\tfrac{y^2}{x}-z\right)+$$
$$+\frac{1}{3}\left(\tfrac{x}{y}+\tfrac{y}{x}-2+\tfrac{y}{z}+\tfrac{z}{x}-\tfrac{y}{x}-1+\tfrac{x}{y}+\tfrac{y}{x}-2+\tfrac{x}{z}+\tfrac{z}{y}-\tfrac{x}{y}-1\right)=$$
$$=\left(\tfrac{(x-y)^2(x+y)}{x^2y^2}+\tfrac{(z-x)(z-y)(x+z)}{x^2z^2}\right)-\left(\tfrac{(x-y)^2(x+y)}{xy}+\tfrac{(z-x)(z-y)(y+z)}{xz}\right)+$$
$$+\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{2(x-y)^2}{xy}+(z-x)(z-y)\left(\frac{1}{xz}+\frac{1}{yz}\right)\right)=$$
$$=(x-y)^2\left(\tfrac{x+y}{x^2y^2}-\tfrac{x+y}{xy}+\tfrac{2}{3xy}\right)+(z-x)(z-y)\left(\tfrac{x+z}{x^2z^2}-\tfrac{y+z}{xz}+\tfrac{x+y}{3xyz}\right).
$$
We'll prove that:$$\frac{x+y}{x^2y^2}-\frac{x+y}{xy}+\frac{2}{3xy}\geq0.$$
Indeed, by the River Li's beautiful point since $x+y\leq2$, by AM-GM we obtain:
$$\frac{x+y}{x^2y^2}-\frac{x+y}{xy}+\frac{2}{3xy}>\frac{x+y}{xy\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2}-\frac{x+y}{xy}\geq0.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that:
$$\frac{x+z}{x^2z^2}-\frac{y+z}{xz}+\frac{x+y}{3xyz}\geq0$$
or

$$\frac{(x+y+z)(x+z)}{xz}+\frac{x+y}{y}+\frac{9x}{x+y+z}-3(x+y+z)\geq0$$ or
$$\frac{x^2+z^2+y(x+z)}{xz}+\frac{x}{y}+\frac{9x}{x+y+z}\geq6$$ or $f(z)\geq0,$ where $$f(z)=yz^3+(x^2-5xy+2y^2)z^2+(x^3+5x^2y-4xy^2+y^3)z+xy(x+y)^2.$$
But $$f''(z)=6yz+2(x^2-5xy+2y^2)\geq$$
$$\geq3y(x+y)+2(x^2-5xy+2y^2)=2x^2-7xy+7y^2>0,$$
which says $$f'(z)=3yz^2+2(x^2-5xy+2y^2)z+x^3+5x^2y-4xy^2+y^3\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{3y(x+y)^2}{4}+(x+y)(x^2-5xy+2y^2)+x^3+5x^2y-4xy^2+y^3=$$
$$=\frac{8x^3+7x^2y-22xy^2+15y^3}{4}>0,$$
which says $$f(z)\geq f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)=\frac{3(x+y)(2x^3+7x^2y-4xy^2+3y^3)}{8}>0.$$

Comment: @youthdoo Because $z\geq\frac{x+y}{2}.$ See the first line of my proof.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg It is very nice. (+1)

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg By the way, using $x + y \le 2$, we have $xy \le (x+y)^2/4 \le 1$, $\frac{x+y}{x^2y^2}-\frac{x+y}{xy} \ge 0$ already.

Comment: @River Li Beautiful point! Thank you! The coefficient before $(z-x)(z-y)$ it's the problem.