# Show positivity of a function of two variables in the unit square.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, polynomials

Let $$
f(x,y) =  x^3 (1 + y + y^2) + y^2 \Big[x^2  (5 + 2 y) + x  (-6 - 4 y + y^2) +  (1 + 3 y + y^2)\Big] 
$$
Show that $f(x,y) \ge 0 $ for $0\le x \le 1$ and $0\le y \le 1$.

Numerical evaluations seem to support the claim.  This is a cubic function in $x$ with one negative coefficient in the linear term, all other coefficients are positive. Since $f(x=0) > 0$, the last two terms guarantee positivity for  $0 < x < 1/6$. The last three terms show a quadratic function which has its minimum always for $x^* \in [0 \quad 1]$,  namely at $x^* = \frac{6 + 4 y - y^2}{10 + 4 y }$ ; however, for small $y$, the value of the sum of the three last terms is negative at $x^*$. How to continue?

Comment: One brute force method is to find the extrema of $f$ over the unit square, by finding critical points inside the square, parametrizing the boundary and finding critical points there, and then comparing to the values at the corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
 f &= (x+1)y^4 + (2x^2 - 4x + 3)y^3 + (x^3 + 5x^2 - 6x + 1)y^2 + x^3y + x^3\\
 &\ge (x+1)y^4 + (2x^2 - 4x + 3)y^4 + (x^3 + 5x^2 - 6x + 1)y^2 + x^3y^2 + x^4 \tag{1}\\
 &= (2x^2 - 3x + 4)y^4 + (2x^3 + 5x^2 - 6x + 1)y^2 + x^4\\
 &\ge (2-x)^2 y^4 + (2x^3 + 5x^2 - 6x + 1)y^2 + x^4\tag{2}\\
 &\ge 2\sqrt{(2-x)^2y^4\cdot x^4} + (2x^3 + 5x^2 - 6x + 1)y^2\tag{3}\\
 &= y^2(3x-1)^2\\
 &\ge 0.
\end{align*}
Explanations:
(1): $(2x^2 - 4x + 3)y^3 \ge (2x^2 - 4x + 3)y^4$ and $x^3y \ge x^3y^2$ and $x^3 \ge x^4$.
(2): $2x^2-3x+4 \ge (2-x)^2$.
(3): AM-GM.

Comment: Elegant and ingenious - a brillant New Year's firework! Thank you River Li.

Comment: @Andreas You are welcome. Happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

The global minimum of $f$ in the compact set $D=\{(x,y): 0\leq x\leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1\}$ will be attained in a stationary point in the interior of $D$ or in a boundary point.

The only stationary point in the interior of $D$ is the point $(0,0)$ and, regarding the boundary,

$$
f(x,0) = x^3 \ge 0, \quad 0\leq x\leq 1$$

$$
f(0,y) = y^2 \left(y^2+3 y+1\right) \ge 0, \quad 0\le y \leq 1
$$

$$
f(x,1) = 3 x^3+7 x^2-9 x+5 \ge 0, \quad 0 \leq x \leq 1
$$

$$
f(1,y)=\left(2 y^2+y\right) y^2+y^2+y+1 \ge 0, \quad 0\leq y \leq 1.
$$

This shows that $f(x,y) \ge 0$ on $D$.

Notes:

1. It is not trivial to show that $(0,0)$ is the only stationary point in the interior of $D$.
2. You still need to solve the one dimensional problems in each portion of the boundary of $D$.
3. This way you can also conclude that $f(x,y)\leq 6$ on $D$.