# Prove $ \frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}\leq \frac{x}{y^2}+\frac{y}{z^2}+\frac{z}{x^2} $ for $x+y+z=3$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Given positive numbers $x,y,z$. If $x+y+z=3$. Prove that
> $$ \frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}\leq \frac{x}{y^2}+\frac{y}{z^2}+\frac{z}{x^2} $$

I know this problem have been already posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4511251/prove-fracxy2-fracyz2-fraczx2-ge-fracx2y-fracy2z). But I'm not able to understand either of the two solutions because they are very long, can't be calculated manually, and a bit unclear. Can't we solve it by applying inequalities like AM-GM, Scur's, Hölder's inequality etc.

I tried applying Cauchy-Schwarz inequality which gave,

$$ \left(\frac{x}{y^2}+\frac{y}{z^2}+\frac{z}{x^2}\right)(x^3+y^3+z^3)\geq \left(\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}\right)^2$$ The task now is to prove
$$\frac{x}{y^2}+\frac{y}{z^2}+\frac{z}{x^2}\geq x^3+y^3+z^3$$ But I'm unable to do so. Can someone help me figure it out?

Comment: some inequalities are just too hard to be solved elementary ideas. Happens more often with cyclic but non-symmetric inequalities.

Comment: Yeah but the last inequality which I wrote according to me can be proven. I am feeling strongly that it must nead a substitution of a function which I am not able to figure.

Comment: For the last inequality, have you tried multiplying by $x^2y^2z^2$ and then using Muirhead's inequality? I haven't tried but it could work  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality

Comment: @AnneBauval both questions are different.

Comment: @JoséAntonio Muirhead's Inequality will't work as LHS will contain two terms in sequence while RHS will contain three terms so we can't apply it.

Comment: This question is *identical* to the referenced one, including the idea to solve it with Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @MartinR, can't you see, I have posted that solution to that identical question isn't clear.