# Prove $2(a+b+c)\left(1+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)\ge 3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$ for $abc=1.$

Tags: inequality, cubics, symmetric-polynomials, uvw

Let $a,b,c>0: abc=1.$ Prove that: $$2(a+b+c)\left(1+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)\ge 3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a). $$

I've tried to use a well-known lemma but the rest is quite complicated for me.

**Lemma.** For any positive real numbers $x,y,z: xyz=1$ then $$\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{x}\ge\sqrt{3(x^2+y^2+z^2)}.$$
*Proof for lemma.*

Obviously, we need prove that $$\frac{x^2}{y^2}+\frac{y^2}{z^2}+\frac{z^2}{x^2}+2\left(\frac{x}{z}+\frac{z}{y}+\frac{y}{x}\right)\ge3(x^2+y^2+z^2).$$

By AM-GM $$\frac{x^2}{y^2}+\frac{x}{z}+\frac{x}{z}\ge3\sqrt[3]{\frac{x^4}{y^2z^2}}=3x^2,$$
$$\frac{y^2}{z^2}+\frac{y}{x}+\frac{y}{x}\ge3\sqrt[3]{\frac{y^4}{x^2z^2}}=3y^2,$$
and
$$\frac{z^2}{x^2}+\frac{z}{y}+\frac{z}{y}\ge3\sqrt[3]{\frac{z^4}{y^2x^2}}=3z^2.$$
Thus, the lemma is proven. Equality holds iff $x=y=z=1.$

Back on the main problem, by applying the lemma, it's enough to prove $$2(a+b+c)\left(1+\sqrt{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)}\right)\ge 3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a). $$

I stopped here. It seems that we can square but it's quite complicated.

Hope you help me prove my last inequality. Thank you for your help.

Comment: We may use $a = x/y, b = y/z, c = z/x$, Then BW (Buffalo Way).

Comment: Could you tel more?

Comment: It is not interesting. Plugging $a = x/y, b = y/z, c = z/x$ into the expression, then WLOG, assume that $z = \min(x, y, z)$, BW: let $x = z + s, y =z + t$ for $s, t \ge 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Proof.**

Firstly, rewrite the inequality as: $$2(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)(a^2c+c^2b+b^2a+1)\ge3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)(ab+bc+ca)$$, $$\iff \frac{1+a^2c+c^2b+b^2a}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}+1+a^2c+c^2b+b^2a\ge\frac{3(ab+bc+ca)}{2},$$
$$\iff 1+a^2c+c^2b+b^2a+\frac{a(a+b)(b+c)+b(b+c)(c+a)+c(c+a)(a+b)-(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}\ge\frac{3(ab+bc+ca)}{2},$$
$$\iff \frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{a}{a+c}+\frac{b}{b+a}+\frac{c}{c+b}\ge\frac{3(ab+bc+ca)}{2},$$
Or $$\frac{a}{b(a+c)}+\frac{b}{c(b+a)}+\frac{c}{a(c+b)}\ge
\frac{3(ab+bc+ca)}{2(a+b+c)}. \tag{*}$$
From here, we can use the lemma you proved.

---

Back on main problem, using C-S inequality and the lemma for (**): $$\frac{\dfrac{ac}{bc}}{a+c}+\frac{\dfrac{ba}{ca}}{a+b}+\frac{\dfrac{cb}{ab}}{b+c}\ge\frac{\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{ab}{bc}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{bc}{ca}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{ca}{ab}}\right)^2}{2(a+b+c)}\ge\frac{3(ab+bc+ca)}{2(a+b+c)}$$The problem is completely proven. Equality holds iff: $a=b=c=1.$

Comment: I try without success. Can you show it?

Comment: I added something, see now.

Comment: @TATAbox It is a tricky way using C-S. (already upvoted yesterday).

Comment: The hardest step is equivalence. It took me a lot of time to verify.

Answer (score 2):

Symmetrization helps.

Indeed, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$, $abc=w^3$ and $u=xw$.

Thus,by AM-GM $x\geq1$ and  we need to prove that
$$u\left(2w^3+2\sum_{cyc}a^2c\right)\geq(9uv^2-w^3)w$$ or
$$u\left(2w^3+\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)\right)-(9uv^2-w^3)w\geq u\sum_{cyc}(a^2b-a^2c)$$ or
$$(u-v)(9uv^2-w^3)\geq u(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$(u-w)^2(9uv^2-w^3)^2\geq u^2\prod_{cyc}(a-b)^2$$ or
$$(u-w)^2(9uv^2-w^3)^2\geq27u^2(3u^2v^4-4v^6-4u^3w^3+6uv^2w^3-w^6)$$ or $f(v^2)\geq0,$ where $$f(v^2)=108u^2v^6-81(2u-w)u^2wv^4-18(10u^2-2uw+w^2)uw^3v^2+108u^5w^3+28u^2w^6-2uw^7+w^8.$$

Now,  $f'(v^2)=0$ gives $$v^2_{min}=\frac{3(2u-w)uw+w\sqrt{36u^4+44u^3w-7u^2w^2+8uw^3}}{12u}=$$
$$=\frac{3(2x-1)x+\sqrt{36x^4+44x^3-7x^2+8x}}{12x}\cdot w^2$$ and it remains to prove that: $f\left(v^2_{min}\right)\geq0$ or
$$648x^5-396x^4+342x^3+107x^2+20x+8\geq\sqrt{(36x^3+44x^2-7x+8)^3x}$$ or
$$9x(648x^5-396x^4+342x^3+107x^2+20x+8)\geq\sqrt{81x^3(36x^3+44x^2-7x+8)^3}.$$
But by AM-GM
$$\sqrt{81x^3(36x^3+44x^2-7x+8)^3}\leq\left(\frac{81x^3+3(36x^3+44x^2-7x+8)}{4}\right)^2.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that:
$$9x(648x^5-396x^4+342x^3+107x^2+20x+8)\geq\left(\frac{81x^3+3(36x^3+44x^2-7x+8)}{4}\right)^2$$ or $$(x-1)^2(6399x^4+918x^3-145x^2+112x-64)\geq0$$  and we are done!

Comment: Now I know what you siad about using $uvw$ for cyclic inequallities. Very nice idea! +1

Comment: Very elegant proof! Thank you and upvote for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Some Remarks**: SOS-Schur method and Buffalo Way (BW)

Using the substitution $a = \frac{y}{x}, b = \frac{z}{y}, c = \frac{x}{z}$, it suffices to prove that, for all $x, y, z > 0$,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \left(2\,{x}^{5}y-3\,{x}^{4}yz-3\,{x}^{3}{y}^{3}+4\,{x}^{3}{y}^{2}z+2\,{x}^{
 2}{y}^{4}-2\,{x}^{2}{y}^{2}{z}^{2}\right)
\ge 0. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

- SOS-Schur method

See: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3423848/prove-fracx2y-fracy2z-fracz2x312-ge-13x3y3z3-for/4711886#4711886), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4511251/prove-fracxy2-fracyz2-fraczx2-ge-fracx2y-fracy2z/4696469#4696469).

WLOG, assume that $z = \max(x, y, z)$. (1) can be written as the form
$$f(x, y, z) = M(x - y)^2 + N(z - x)(z - y)$$
where $M, N \ge 0$.

There are many such $M, N$.

For example, [Andreas' method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4511251/prove-fracxy2-fracyz2-fraczx2-ge-fracx2y-fracy2z):
\begin{align*}
 M &= {x}^{3}y+{x}^{3}z+2\,{x}^{2}{y}^{2}+{x}^{2}yz+x{y}^{3}+x{y}^{2}z+{y}^{
  3}z
 , \\
 N &= {x}^{4}-{x}^{3}z-{x}^{2}{y}^{2}+3\,{x}^{2}yz+2\,{x}^{2}{z}^{2}+2\,x{y}
 ^{3}+x{y}^{2}z\\
 &\qquad -xy{z}^{2}+2\,x{z}^{3}-{y}^{4}-{y}^{3}z+2\,{y}^{2}{z}^{2
 }.
\end{align*}
(*Note*: It is not difficult to prove that $N \ge 0$.)

Using computer, we can obtain the same $M, N$ as Andreas' one.
We can also obtain the following:
\begin{align*}
 M &= 2\,{x}^{3}y+3\,{x}^{2}{y}^{2}-{x}^{2}yz+{x}^{2}{z}^{2}+x{y}^{3}+xy{z}^
 {2}+{y}^{3}z, \\
 N &= {x}^{3}y-{x}^{3}z+3\,{x}^{2}yz+2\,{x}^{2}{z}^{2}+x{y}^{3}+x{y}^{2}z-xy
 {z}^{2}+2\,x{z}^{3}\\
 &\qquad -{y}^{4}-{y}^{3}z+2\,{y}^{2}{z}^{2}.
\end{align*}
(*Note*: It is easy to prove that $M, N\ge 0$.)

- BW (Buffalo Way):

WLOG, assume that $z = \max(x, y, z)$.
Let $x = \frac{z}{1 + s}, y = \frac{z}{1 + t}$ for $s, t \ge 0$.
(1) is equivalently written as
\begin{align*}
 &2\,{s}^{4}{t}^{5}+2\,{s}^{5}{t}^{3}+7\,{s}^{4}{t}^{4}+8\,{s}^{3}{t}^{5
 }+3\,{s}^{5}{t}^{2}+18\,{s}^{4}{t}^{3}+32\,{s}^{3}{t}^{4}\\
&\qquad +9\,{s}^{2}{t
 }^{5}+21\,{s}^{4}{t}^{2}+62\,{s}^{3}{t}^{3}+39\,{s}^{2}{t}^{4}+4\,s{t}
 ^{5}+{s}^{5}+3\,{s}^{4}t\\
 &\qquad +60\,{s}^{3}{t}^{2}+72\,{s}^{2}{t}^{3}+17\,s{t
 }^{4}+{t}^{5}+5\,{s}^{4}+12\,{s}^{3}t+63\,{s}^{2}{t}^{2}\\
&\qquad +28\,s{t}^{3}+
 5\,{t}^{4}+10\,{s}^{3}+9\,{s}^{2}t+17\,s{t}^{2}+10\,{t}^{3}+8\,{s}^{2}
 -8\,st+8\,{t}^{2}\\
 &\ge 0
\end{align*}
which is clearly true.

Comment: Very useful proof!